# Why gapped systems are called incompressible?

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, quantum-hall-effect, fermi-liquids

I study quantum Hall systems and I haven't studied Fermi liquid theory yet. But I understand the concept of having gap or being gapless. But why do we use the term *incompressibility* to correspond the presence of gap in the bulk state? Is there any relation to physical compressibility here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The electronic compressibility $\kappa$ is defined as 
$$\kappa =\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \mu} $$
where $\rho$ is the electron density, and $\mu$ the chemical potential. The region where the $\rho(\mu)$ is constant indeed indicates that there is an energy gap. This can simply be understood by the fact that in the energy gap there is a region where there are no electronic states that can contribute to the electronic density $\rho$, and thus it remains constant. The region of $\mu$ values over which $\rho$ remains constant determines the energy gap.

The criterion often used for insulating behavior is that there is a certain region where $\kappa$ vanishes. However, keep in mind that this criterion for insulating behavior applies to standard insulators, as well as electron-driven insulators (e.g. Mott insulator). Nonetheless, there are insulators where $\kappa$ does not vanishes, these are disorder-induced Anderson insulator. So keep in mind that this is not a universal characterization for insulating behavior!

Comment: Thanks @Simon for the answer. Can you suggest me some reading material which discusses the compressibility, assuming my knowledge of graduate level condensed matter theory?

Comment: I encountered this concept in these lecture notes: https://juser.fz-juelich.de/record/837488/files/correl17.pdf Take a look at chapter 2, which is the chapter on criteria for insulators etc.