# What is the code distance in quantum information theory?

Tags: quantum-information, topological-order, symmetry-breaking

What is the [code](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29310/what-is-code-in-toric-code) distance in quantum information theory?
Code distance seems to be a very important concept in fault tolerant
quantum computation and topological quantum computation.

Comment: Since this is way out of my  field  of expertise I will not presume to answer, but the link provided in another question http://www.qip2010.ethz.ch/tutorialprogram/JiannisPachosLecture defines also the code distance as "The distance k of the code C is the minimal length among the
elements of Z(S)\S up to a sign. Such elements serve as encoded logical operations. For
an efficient encoding we thus assume that the errors are less than [k/2]-local."

Comment: Thanks for the link. The code distance suppose to be a distance between two objects. But what are these two objects?

Comment: still wading: at 2.1.1 "A general k-local operator O is an operator that acts non-trivially to at most k subsystems of H (also known as operator of
length k)." seems to define length for a local operator. So one has to count the subsystems of H  on which the operator acts non trivially to get its length, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than give a more mathematical answer, to which I'll refer you to [another answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/29461/9627), let me give you slightly less precise explanation. Basically, the distance is the shortest path in a certain "space of errors" which maps between two orthogonal quantum states that are in the code. The natural space of errors is that of single qubit errors of the form $\sigma_X$, $\sigma_Y$ or $\sigma_z$, in the case where the Hilbert space is that of $n$ qubits. So you can think of distance as the shortest path to get from one state to another by operations on single qubits, applied one at a time sequentially.

Comment: If two states can be connected by a sequence of $\sigma_X$, $\sigma_Y$, and $\sigma_Z$ operations, then the code distance is the minimal number of the single qubit operations that transform one state into the other. But if  two states can NOT be connected by a sequence of $\sigma_X$, $\sigma_Y$, and $\sigma_Z$ operations, can we still define the code distance?

Comment: The code distance can be defined in terms of the weight of the correctible Kraus operators using the Knill-Laflamme quantum error correction criterion.  For example, a rigorous definition in this framework can be found in Page 2 of the reference: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379517303956?via%3Dihub or https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07925