# Definition of mass gap

Tags: quantum-field-theory, radiation, mass-energy

Why do we say that a system with mass gap has correlation function which decays exponentially and one without a mass gap has a slower power law decay?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a mass gap?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30574/)

Comment: Note: The linked possible duplicate does not carry out the computation that shows that mass gap $\Leftrightarrow$ exponentially decaying correlation functions. However, this falls out of simply *computing* said correlation functions for a theory with mass gap and without - just like the $\mathrm{e}^{-\mu^2 r}$ appears when one calculates the potential associated to a force mediated by massive force carriers.

Comment: Is there any physical intuition which shows this. Also do mass gap and gapped systems mean the same thing?